# After rolling of 3 dice, no two faces are the same; what is the probability there was a $1$?

Tags: probability

> Three dice were rolled. Given that no two faces were same,What is the probability that there was a "$1$"?

I'm solving it like this.

$A$: event that there was "$1$"

$B$: event that no two faces were same.

Using Conditional probability

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

But I'm not able to figure out the probabilities for event $B$.

Answer (score 4):

$$P(B)=\frac{n(\text{no two faces were the same on $3$ dice)}}{n(\text{rolls of $3$ dice)}}$$

To find how many rolls of three dice will have no two faces the same, think of each die in turn.

The first die can be any number: $6$ possibilities.

The second die can be any other number: $5$ possibilities.

The third die can be any number different from the first two: $4$ possibilities.

Therefore the equation becomes

$$P(B)=\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{6^3}$$

---

You could also think in terms of probabilities. The first die can be anything: probability of success is $1$. The second die then has a probability of $\frac 56$ of being different from the first. If that is a success, the third die has a probability of $\frac 46$ of being different from the first two. That gives a final probability of

$$P(B)=1\cdot\frac 56\cdot\frac 46$$

This is the same as my first answer, of course.

---

To find $P(A\cap B)$ we want $n(A\cap B)$ which is the number of ways to get three different numbers on three dice where one of the numbers was $1$.

There are three exclusive cases: The first die was $1$, the second die was $1$, or the third die was $1$. Counting the first case:

The first die was $1$: $1$ possibility.

The second die was different: $5$ possibilities.

The third die was yet different: $4$ possibilities.

Therefore, the number of possibilities for our first case is $1\cdot 5\cdot 4$. Clearly the second and third cases each have the same number of possibilities. The cases are mutually exclusive, so we can just add their counts. Therefore,

$$n(A\cap B)=3\cdot 1\cdot 5\cdot 4$$
$$P(A\cap B)=\frac{3\cdot 1\cdot 5\cdot 4}{6^3}$$

---

All this will lead to a simple answer for $P(A\mid B)$. But there was an easier way to find that. For every way to throw three dice with three different numbers and get a $1$ there is also a way to throw three dice with three different numbers and *not* get a $1$: namely, the other three numbers that we did *not* get in our throw. Therefore, all throws of three dice with different numbers are equally divided between those with a $1$ and those without. The conditional probability is thus just one half.

Comment: Thanks Rory but what exactly is the number in the numerator? I tried like 1- P(getting 2 same faces).  Will it be 6*1*5 ? 6 ways of getting a number on 1st die and then 1 way of getting the same on 2nd and 5 ways for 3rd one?

Comment: See my answer as it stands now. The number in the numerator is $6\cdot 5\cdot 4$.

Comment: Great! I got you. Also if you could confirm the P( A intersection B)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment, sorry, so I'll add some help through an answer.
You know that

P(A=1) = $\frac{3}{18}$=$\frac{1}{6}$ and $P(A^{c})$=$\frac{15}{18}$ = $\frac{5}{6}$ to start.